# Combine two dataframes and pick first entry based on common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like

df1

```py
sub_id     Weight
1          56
2          67
3          81
5          73
9          59
```

df2

```py
sub_id     Text
1          He is normal.
1          person is healthy.
1          has strong immune power.
3          She is over weight.
3          person is small.
9          Looks good.
5          Not well.
5          Need to be tested.
```

By combining these two data frame i need to get as
(when there are multiple sub_id's in second df need to pick first text and combine with first df as below)

merge_df

```
sub_id   Weight    Text
1        56        He is normal.
2        67        Nan.
3        81        She is over weight.
5        73        Not well.
9        59        Looks good.
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('sub_id'))` or something similar should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
print(pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates(subset='sub_id'),
         on='sub_id',
         how='outer'))
```

Output

```
   sub_id  Weight                 Text
0       1      56        He is normal.
1       2      67                  NaN
2       3      81  She is over weight.
3       5      73            Not well.
4       9      59          Looks good.
```

To keep the last duplicate, you'd use the parameter `keep='last'`

```py
print(pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates(subset='sub_id', keep='last'),
         on='sub_id',
         how='outer'))
```

Output

```
   sub_id  Weight                      Text
0       1      56  has strong immune power.
1       2      67                       NaN
2       3      81          person is small.
3       5      73        Need to be tested.
4       9      59               Looks good.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.... I have other question.. what if i want to pick the last duplicate entry instead of first .... for example for the sub_id 1 i have to get Text as has strong immune power

Comment: @RahulThangellapally updated the post to keep the last duplicate